# PowerEdge T30 - how to create RAID 1?

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Dell PowerEdge T30 server and I need to create the raid mirror (Raid 1). How do I do it?

I looked at the BIOS and set RAID to On.

Then I tried pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> but the system will not load into the RAID Configuration Utility.

The server is running Windows Server 2012R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you purchased an optional hardware storage controller, you do not have a pre-boot storage controller option.

By default, your only option for RAID on this computer is the Intel Rapid Storage Controller: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/ie/en/iebsdt1/poweredge-t30/pet30_om/storage-controller-card-specifications?guid=guid-bbe85bde-727a-4f8f-95cc-2acd4190bb09&lang=en-us

According to Dell (https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln288974/how-to-create-a-raid-1-volume-within-windows-using-the-intel-rapid-storage-technology-utility) you need two drives minimum installed in the computer and then you follow these steps:

In Windows open the Intel Rapid Storage Technology software and choose Create from the options at the top.

Select Real-time data protection.

In the Configure screen, give a name and select the disks you wish to assign to the volume and choose whether or not to keep the data on the volumes. If you are adding your OS drive to this array be very careful and make sure you have a backup.

Confirm creation of the volume.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will think about buying an optional hardware storage controller.

Comment: Use the checkmark icon to indicate this is the correct answer to your question.